# Help me find a book about a boy and a drawing bug

Tags: identification-request

My teacher read me this book sometime between 2012-2016. The book is about a bug (I'm pretty sure it's a beetle) who is able to draw amazing pictures. He lives in a boy's room and the boy's mom thinks that her son drew the pictures. The boy and the beetle team up to make art, *à la* "Ratatouille". At the end of the book, the boy can't handle the lie so he breaks his hand by closing a car door on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it was a beetle: This is probably *[Masterpiece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece_(novel))*, by [Elise Broach](https://www.elisebroach.com/):

> Marvin lives with his family under the kitchen sink in the Pompadays' apartment. He is very much a beetle. James Pompaday lives with his family in New York City. He is very much an eleven-year-old boy. After James gets a pen-and-ink set for his birthday, Marvin surprises him by creating an elaborate miniature drawing. James gets all the credit for the picture and before these unlikely friends know it they are caught up in a staged art heist at the Metropolitan Museum of Art that could help recover a famous drawing by Albrecht Dürer. But James can't go through with the plan without Marvin's help. And that's where things get really complicated (and interesting!).
> [[From the Amazon blurb]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312608705)